# Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter' to type 'MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from MySql database in my ASP.Net core 5 API.

My Database context:

```
public class SharedDBContext : BaseDbContext
{
    #region Variables

    private readonly BaseUserContext _currentUserContext;

    #endregion Variables
    public SharedDBContext(DbContextOptions<SharedDBContext> options, BaseUserContext userContext) : base(options, userContext)
    {
        this._currentUserContext = userContext;
    }

    public void AddAuditTrail(int userAccountId, string actionName, bool isError, string description, string details)
    {
        List<MySqlParameter> paramList = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("userAccountId", userAccountId));
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("actionName", actionName));
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("isError", isError));
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("description", description));
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("details", details));
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("createdDate", DateTime.UtcNow));

        this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"AuditTrail_INSERT @PARAMS", paramList);
    }
}
```

My Services class is:

```
public class AuditTrailService : IAuditTrailService
{
    private readonly SharedDBContext _dBContext;

    public AuditTrailService(SharedDBContext dBContext)
    {
        _dBContext = dBContext;
    }

    public void AddAuditTrail(int userAccountId, string actionName, bool isError, string description, string details)
    {
        _dBContext.AddAuditTrail(userAccountId, actionName, isError, description, details);
    }
}
```

I made sure to dependency inject the services in the start up.

Finally, in my API, when I try calling the AddAuditTrail function, I get the following error:

{"Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter' to type 'MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter'."}

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `AuditTrail_INSERT`(
userAccountId int,
actionName VARCHAR(30),
isError TINYINT(1),
description VARCHAR(1024),
details VARCHAR(1024),
createdDate DATETIME(6)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO base_auditTrail(
    UserAccountId, ActionName, IsError, Description, Details, 
    CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, IsDeleted,
    DeletedDate, DeletedBy
    ) 
    VALUES(userAccountId, actionName, isError, description, details, null, null, 
    createdDate, null, 0, null, null);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySqlParameter` exists in 2 namespaces: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` and `MySqlConnector`. You need the latter. Look at your using statements on the top of the file and replace `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` with `using MySqlConnector;`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But please help me. Now the error changed to {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AuditTrail_INSERT @PARAMS' at line 1"}

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced with sql syntax and stored procedures, You are better open an additional question.

Comment: @NourMawla You are probably missing a `CALL` statement in your SQL? `this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"CALL AuditTrail_INSERT(@userAccountId, @actionName, @isError, @description, @details, @createdDate)", paramList);`